# Having trouble with creating arrays in a for loop and scoping

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, scope, nullreferenceexception

I have to assign values to members(I don't know if this is the right term) of an array. I delcared my array members as follow: (all this code is inside a public class BWClass)

```
public static BackgroundWorker[] bwCA = new BackgroundWorker[25];
public static int NumbwCA;
private static bool HasRunOnce = false;
public static void BackgroundWorkerInitializer(bool doFirst, int numbwCA)
{

    // Okay we got here. So we can presume that array checking (number not exceeding the array) is already done
    if (!HasRunOnce)
    {
        NumbwCA = numbwCA; // for access 
    } // Now it is impossible to stop less backgroundworkers then started later on in the code
    if (doFirst)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumbwCA; i++)
        {
            string strpara = (numbwCA.ToString()); // Could also directly write numbwCA.ToString() directly in the RunWorkerAsync() method

            bwCA = new BackgroundWorker[NumbwCA];
            bwCA[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
            bwCA[i].WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bwCA[i].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bwCA[i].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bwa_DoWork);
            bwCA[i].ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bwa_ProgressChanged);
            bwCA[i].RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bwa_RunWorkerCompleted);

            bwCA[i].RunWorkerAsync(strpara);
        }
    }
    else // DoSecond
    {
        // stop the backgroundworkers
        for (int i = 0; i < NumbwCA; i++)
        {
            if (bwCA[i].IsBusy == true)
            {
                bwCA[i].CancelAsync();
                HasRunOnce = false; // If restarting the server is required. The user won't have to restart the progrem then
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">>The backgroundworkers are already finished and don't need canceling");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al this code is inside a public class.
I thought that when I do all the array making in a class I won't have the problem of variable scopes anymore. But I was wrong. I still get the Error nullReferenceException when the bwCA[i].IsBusy == true runs. Probably also when anything outside the for loop runs.

I know that I can't use the bwCA[i] outside the loop were it is declared but how do I change this, so that I can access bwCA[i] (anywhere) else in the code (like in the "else // DoSecond)?

btw. I prefer not to use a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the array creation outside the loop

```
// here for instance
bwCA = new BackgroundWorker[NumbwCA];

if (doFirst)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NumbwCA; i++)
    {
        string strpara = (numbwCA.ToString()); 
       // bwCA = new BackgroundWorker[NumbwCA];
```

That still leaves a few issues with cleanup and running this Initializer twice.

More general, try to avoid `static` stuff and you shouldn't be needing 25 Backgroundworkers in the first place.

Tasks are probably more appropriate but we can't tell.

Comment: I want to use the backgroundworkers for handling tcpclients. But I am sure that tasks are more appropiate here. Thanks